# Regular expression for CLR (C#) in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, regex, oracle, ssis, clr

I have below Oracle regular expression that validates email-id. I need to convert this into its equivalent `regex` that I can use in `CLR` program in `SSIS`.

```
/^(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\'\-\.])@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/
```

Can someone pls help me convert?

***In plain english below is the rule:***

1.An email should start with any non-white space character

2. Preceding with zero or more characters from the list of: a-z A-Z 0-9 - _ .
3. @(at symbol)
4. Any character from the list of: a-z A-Z 0-9 - _ .
5. .(dot symbol)
6. Any character from the list of: a-z A-Z 
   between the size of 2 to 5 characters.

Comment: Do you want to use it in C# or VB script task in SSIS

Comment: Thanks. I want the C# equivalent please.

Comment: There is nothin to convert. Just use the pattern in the string literal, `@"^(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\'\-\.])@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"`. But there is a mistake: you omitted `+` quantifiers, so it should be `@"^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_'.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$"`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor.I have used "^\s*[A-Za-z0-9.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-_]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$". But this is saying emails like "srard-mail.gmail.com" to be invalid. But according to my rule: hyphen in local part of email is valid. Hence I changed it to @"^(\s*[A-Za-z0-9\.\-_])+@([A-Za-z0-9\.\-_])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,5})$" Do you think of any issues of my regex?